# Node.js and express Rest api to create custom fields routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, npm

I am working with node.js and express framework for my rest api server.

I have created `get` routes with query params and working with them.

But I want to make a functionality like facebook graph api where I can send fields with my api routes such as

```
/me?fields=address,birthday,email,domains.limit(10){id,name,url}
```

I am thinking of getting the fields from the query parameters and then splitting them based on , such as

```
const fields = req.query.fields;
let fieldsArray = fields.split(',');
```

But how can I pass the sub object attributes and retrieve them from the route like domain field from the above example.

/me?fields=address,birthday,email,**domains.limit(10){id,name,url}**

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output will be like retrieving the fields from the routes and getting those attributes from the database. For more clear explanation you can use facebook graph api tool

Comment: Do you want the `id,name,url` fields of `domains`? You might enjoy using a dot notation

Comment: @aec can you please help me with a example that will be very helpful

Comment: also GraphQL might be interesting to look at too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a dot-notation like so

```
/me?fields=address,domains.id,domains.name&dbQueryFilters=domains.limit=10
```

It could mean:

- I want these fields in my response:

  - address
  - domains:

    - id
    - name
- Use these to query the db:

  - domains:

    - limit :10

You can add/remove such query variables until it explicitly conveys what your API does while still being very basic. It's always in your best interest to keep things simple and basic.

On the nodeJS side, you can use a library like [flat](https://github.com/hughsk/flat) to unflatten the query object:

`var fields = flat.unflatten(req.query.fields)`

Answer (score 0):

Try sending out the request like:

```
/me?fields=address,birthday,email,domains.limit%2810%29%7Bid%2Cname%2Curl%7D
```

There is code for every special character you can get it by doing:

```
escape("domains.limit(10){id,name,url}") // Returns domains.limit%2810%29%7Bid%2Cname%2Curl%7D
```

More details: [JavaScript escape() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp)

Hope this solves your issue.